# odoo 8. Check whether the country enters the group of countries

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I shall be grateful for the help in some questions.

In odoo 8 I have created several groups of countries (res.country.group).

Where the user has chosen a country I need to check:

1. In which groups this country is included
2. Whether this country is included in the appropriate group

How to do it in a new API?

For example, I turned the country Belarus into the group of countries: Europe, CIS.

We heal patients from many countries.
According to the law if the patient from the CIS countries, all documents should be in two languages at the same time - in Ukrainian and Russian.
If the patient from any other country is in Ukrainian and English.

I have three fields groups in each language.
When the patient is a foreigner, the corresponding field is True.
When a patient from CIS countries display_name = name in Ukrainian (name in Russian). 
When a patient from any other country display_name = name in Ukrainian (name in English).

In this example I need to check country_id in CIS country group or not.

```
@api.one
@api.depends('foreigner', 'name', 'rus_name', 'eng_name')
def _display_name_compute(self):
    if self.name:
        self.display_name = self.name
    else:
        self.display_name = ''

    if self.foreigner:
        self.display_name = self.display_name + ' ('
        cis_id = self.env['res.country.group'].search([('name','like','CIS')])
        cis_ids = self.env['res.country.group'].browse([cis_id]).country_ids

        if self.country_id.id in cis_ids:
            if self.rus_name:
                self.display_name = self.display_name + self.rus_name + ')'
        else:
             if self.eng_name:
                 self.display_name = self.display_name + self.eng_name + ')'
        self.display_name = self.display_name + ')'
```

Comment: checking in different places ...if self.foreigner:
                self.display_name = self.display_name + ' ('
                if self.country_id.id in self.country_id.country_group_ids:
                    if self.rus_name:
                        self.display_name = self.display_name + self.rus_name + ')'
                else:
                    if self.eng_name:
                        self.display_name = self.display_name + self.eng_name + ')'
                self.display_name = self.display_name + ')'

Comment: In this example, I need to check the selected country is included in the CIS or not. If so, what it is shown on the Russian, or English.

Comment: please update that example your question.